# Software versions vary between test and production site

Tags: php, mysql, apache, joomla

I have a Joomla! 1.5 site I badly need to upgrade to v.3. Since I last worked on it, I bought a new laptop, and downloaded the latest version of WampServer to build a development site.  Unfortunately, since the first time I installed it, Wampserver seems to have changed.  I never had any trouble getting the exact version of Apache, mySQL, and PHP that my production site had.  But this time I can't get a version match at all.  The Wamp download extras all seem to be a little backleveled.

Production runs Apache 2.2.23; Wamp offers only 2.2.22.
Production runs mySQL 5.0.91; Wamp comes with 5.5.24; the latest 5.0 version it offers is 5.0.88.
Production runs PHP 5.3.27; latest version Wamp offers is 5.3.0.

I figure the difference between the 2 Apache versions probably isn't an issue - but it looks like a long way from mySQL 5.0.91 to 5.5.24. Should I load 5.0.88 in development and hope Joomla 3 won't need anything in the intervening updates.  Same question applies to PHP - how much does PHP 5.3.27 differ from PHP 5.3.0?

I was trained that a development site should use the same software versions as the production site it supports.  How important is that?  What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Wamp offers Apache 2.2.22 however you can download the addon 2.2.3 so that is not a problem. As for MySQL, well you want to stay clear of old versions such as 5.0.91 and start using 5.5+. As for PHP, well I would recommend either using 5.3 or 5.4, preferably 5.4 as it's the way forward.

You need to start getting your site running with the latest technologies.

Have a look at the [Joomla requirements](http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html)

you basically want to set up your dev environment with up to date technologies, test your site and ensure everything works fine.

there will be some 3rd party extensions that you will need to replace with Joomla 3.x compatible ones.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  Apache 2.2.23 is NOW available, I don't think it was when I checked a few weeks ago.  Now it's there, I'll grab it.  Sounds as though I should upgrade mySQL and PHP on my production site, too, I'll check that with my ISP. As for PHP, 5.3.13 is the latest add-on Wampserver offers with Apache 2.2.x (yes I was wrong).  I hate to backlevel production to match the dev site.